# MonoGame + TiledSharp Collision

Tags: collision-detection, monogame, tiled

I am using Tiled (http://www.mapeditor.org) to generate my maps and TiledSharp (https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp) to load and draw my map.

So far so good. Map is drawn correcty (in correct layers) and hero movement is correct.

What I do not get. How to check collision between player and objects?

In my Update() I have something like

```
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
{
    playerMovement += new Vector2(0, -2);
    curAnimation = "Walk_North";
}

...

if (playerMovement.Length() != 0)
    player.MoveBy(playerMovement);
```

Checking the .tmx file for the map, there is my group with object I can collide with:

```
 <objectgroup name="Collision">
  <properties>
   <property name="collision" type="bool" value="true"/>
  </properties>
  <object id="1" x="1089" y="1118" width="62" height="65"/>
  <object id="2" x="801" y="1026" width="61" height="60"/>
 </objectgroup>
```

What I am now looking for is something like

```
If(tileAt(player.Position + playerMovement).Properties.Collision)
    playerMovement = Vector2.Zero();
```

I think, everything is I need is there and I am just missing a simple step to compare players' position with the target position and its property :(

Any suggestions or examples would be appreciated.
(Maybe just need to calculate it by myself in a simple method...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, actually quite easy:

First, in my class managing my map I set up an List with my collisionobjects.

```
foreach(var o in curMap.ObjectGroups["Collision"].Objects)
    collisionObjects.Add(new Rectangle((int)o.X, (int)o.Y, (int)o.Width, (int)o.Height));
```

In my UpdateGame() method I call a simple helper-method from my map-class checking for intersection:

```
public bool IsCollisionTile(Rectangle player)
{
    foreach (Rectangle rect in collisionObjects)
        if (rect.Intersects(player))
           return true;

    return false;
}
```

Finished.

More effort writing this posting than the actual implementation ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code but he don't work when I launch my game one exception display in the foreach he say the key is not found on dictionary

Its my class MapLoader

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using TiledSharp;

namespace TestMapLoader
{
    public class MapLoader
    {
        private TmxMap _map;
        private Texture2D _tileset;
        private int _tileWidth;
        private int _tileHeight;
        private int _mapWidth;
        private int _mapHeight;
        private int _tilesetTilesWide;
        private int _tilesetTilesHigh;
        private List<Rectangle> _collisionObject;

        public MapLoader()
        {
        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager content, string path)
        {
            _collisionObject = new List<Rectangle>();

            _map = new TmxMap(path);
            _tileset = content.Load<Texture2D>(_map.Tilesets[0].Name.ToString());

            _tileWidth = _map.Tilesets[0].TileWidth;
            _tileHeight = _map.Tilesets[0].TileHeight;

            _tilesetTilesWide = _tileset.Width / _tileWidth;
            _tilesetTilesHigh = _tileset.Height / _tileHeight;

            _mapWidth = _map.Width;
            _mapHeight = _map.Height;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch ,int nbLayer)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            for (int nLayer = 0; nLayer < nbLayer; nLayer++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < _map.Layers[nLayer].Tiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    int gid = _map.Layers[nLayer].Tiles[i].Gid;

                    if (gid != 0)
                    {
                        int tileFrame = gid - 1;
                        int column = tileFrame % _tilesetTilesWide;
                        int row = (int)Math.Floor((double)tileFrame / (double)_tilesetTilesWide);

                        int mapRow = (int)(i / _mapWidth);
                        int mapColumn = i % _mapWidth;

                        float x = (i % _map.Width) * _map.TileWidth;
                        float y = (float)Math.Floor(i / (double)_map.Width) * _map.TileHeight;

                        Rectangle tilesetRec = new Rectangle(_tileWidth * column, _tileHeight * row, _tileWidth, _tileHeight);

                        spriteBatch.Draw(_tileset, new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, _tileWidth, _tileHeight), tilesetRec, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
            foreach(var o in _map.ObjectGroups["Collision"].Objects)
            {
                this._collisionObject.Add(new Rectangle((int)o.X, (int)o.Y, (int)o.Width, (int)o.Height));
            }
        }

        public bool IsCollisionTile(Rectangle player)
        {
            foreach(Rectangle rect in this._collisionObject)
            {
                if (rect.Intersects(player))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public TmxMap getMap()
        {
            return _map;
        }
    }
}
```

I call all function in my Game1 class

Comment: First, you should NOT add the foreach inside Draw(). in this case you add all collisionObjects 60 times per second (@60FPS) that's quite insane ;)

I've added the foreach in the TileMap constructor since you need to fill the collision object only once per map (assuming you load the map at once)

Second:
Check your .tmx file for the following
 <objectgroup name="Obstacles">
  <object id="1" x="96" y="1054.67" width="96" height="64.3333"/>
  <object id="2" x="479" y="1119.5" width="68" height="66.5"/>
and so on
</objectgroup>

The name of the group is case sensitive!